# How to run SearchHeadline (a heavy function) only on the Paginated QuerySet result

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using Django and Postgresql Full-Text Search to generate a paginated search result for my users. I rank and highlight my results.

```
qs = (
    self.filter(Q(title_vector=SearchQuery(search_term)))
    .annotate(rank=rank)
    .order_by("-rank", "pk")
    .annotate(
        title_snippet=SearchHeadline(
            "title",
            SearchQuery(search_term),
            highlight_all=True
        )
    )
    .distinct()
)
```

In performance testing, I've identified that the SearchHeadline function is extremely heavy (as mentioned in the documentation) and *is applied to every single row in the result* - even if there are thousands of results being paginated in sets of 25. This makes the query take too long to complete. Another user on StackOverflow had the same issue as mine and discovered that only running `ts_headline` against the paginated results significantly improves performance ([Relevant Question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16107044/13212499)). I tested and confirmed that a similar approach would solve my problem.

My question is how can I tweak my Django code to generate a SQL query against a query like the below example? After the Paginator applies a limit and offset to the result set, only **then** run `ts_headline` against those results only.

```
SELECT
    id,
    ts_headline('italian', body, to_tsquery('italian', 'torino')) as headline,
    rank,
    title,
    location
FROM (
    SELECT
        id,
        body,
        title,
        location,
        ts_rank(body_tsvector, query) as rank
    FROM
        fulltextsearch.documents, to_tsquery('italian', 'torino') as query
    WHERE
        to_tsvector('italian', coalesce(body,'')) @@ query
    LIMIT 10
    OFFSET 0
) as s
```

EDIT:
Here is the current (unoptimized) query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       "dockets_document"."title", 
       "dockets_document"."content", 
       "dockets_document"."title_vector", 
       "dockets_document"."search_vector", 
       (1 * ts_rank("dockets_document"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'hearing'))) AS "rank", 
       ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, "dockets_document"."title", to_tsquery('hearing'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', HighlightAll=true') AS "title_snippet", 
       ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, array_to_string("dockets_document"."content", ' ', ''), to_tsquery('hearing'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', MaxFragments=5') AS "content_snippet" 
  FROM "dockets_document" 
 WHERE 
 "dockets_document"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'hearing') 
 ORDER BY "rank" DESC, "dockets_document"."id" ASC 
 LIMIT 25;
```

Here is the hand-edited desired query (10x speedup):

```
SELECT 
    ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, title, to_tsquery('hearing'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', HighlightAll=true') AS "title_snippet",
    ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, array_to_string(content, ' ', ''), to_tsquery('hearing'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', MaxFragments=5') AS "content_snippet" 
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT  
       "dockets_document"."title" as title, 
       "dockets_document"."content" as content, 
       (1 * ts_rank("dockets_document"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'hearing'))) AS "rank"
  FROM "dockets_document" 
 WHERE 
 "dockets_document"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'hearing') 
 ORDER BY "rank" DESC, "dockets_document"."id" ASC 
 LIMIT 25 ) as s;
```

**EDIT 2**
The DISTINCT is the problem.

Here is my full query to see how I could eliminate the DISTINCT:

```
SELECT "dockets_document"."id", 
       "dockets_document"."title", 
       "dockets_document"."url", 
       "dockets_document"."content", 
       "dockets_document"."num_tables", 
       "dockets_document"."num_pages", 
       "dockets_document"."tables_processed", 
       "dockets_document"."summary", 
       "dockets_document"."importance", 
       "dockets_document"."title_vector", 
       "dockets_document"."search_vector", 
       "dockets_document"."datetime_created", 
       "dockets_document"."datetime_modified", 
       "dockets_document"."docket_id", 
       "dockets_document"."docket_number", 
       "dockets_document"."date_filed", 
       "dockets_document"."pdf", 
       ((((1 * ts_rank("dockets_document"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead'))) + (0.8 * ts_rank("dockets_attachment"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead')))) + (1.0 * ts_rank("dockets_table"."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead')))) + (0.8 * ts_rank(T5."search_vector", plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead')))) AS "rank", 
       ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, "dockets_document"."title", to_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', HighlightAll=true') AS "title_snippet", 
       ts_headline('public.bb'::regconfig, CONCAT(array_to_string("dockets_document"."content", ' ', ''), CONCAT(array_to_string("dockets_attachment"."content", ' ', ''), CONCAT(array_to_string("dockets_table"."content", ' ', ''), array_to_string(T5."content", ' ', '')))), to_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead'), 'StartSel=''<mark>'', StopSel=''</mark>'', MaxFragments=5') AS "content_snippet" 
  FROM "dockets_document" 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "dockets_attachment" 
    ON ("dockets_document"."id" = "dockets_attachment"."main_document_id") 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "dockets_table" 
    ON ("dockets_document"."id" = "dockets_table"."object_id" AND ("dockets_table"."content_type_id" = 8)) 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN "dockets_table" T5 
    ON ("dockets_attachment"."id" = T5."object_id" AND (T5."content_type_id" = 24)) 
 WHERE ("dockets_document"."docket_id" = 'p_LATAM' AND NOT ("dockets_document"."title_vector" @@ ((((((((phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'pro hac') || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'certificate of mailing')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'affidavit/declaration of mailing')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'request for service')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'certification of counsel')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'certification of no objection')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'receipt of filing fee')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'affidavit of service')) || phraseto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'Transfer/Assignment of Claim')) AND "dockets_document"."title_vector" IS NOT NULL) AND ("dockets_document"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead') OR "dockets_attachment"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead') OR "dockets_table"."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead') OR T5."search_vector" @@ plainto_tsquery('public.bb'::regconfig, 'knighthead')) AND "dockets_document"."num_pages" >= 0 AND "dockets_document"."num_tables" >= 0) 
 ORDER BY "rank" DESC, "dockets_document"."id" ASC 
 LIMIT 25
```

Comment: What versions of Django and PostgreSQL are you using?  What is the *current* query that django generates?

Comment: Using PostgreSQL 10x and Django 3.2. 
Editing the comment to show current and desired query

Comment: In my hands, it is the DISTINCT that causes the problem.  Is that really necessary?  Without that, PostgreSQL automatically defers the headline computation, and it should be easy to remove it in Django.

Comment: I see. You are correct, removing the DISTINCT sped up the query by 70%. The DISTINCT is necessary because I'm actually searching not just for Documents, but also Tables (spreadsheets embedded in each document) and Attachments (exhibits to the main document). As such my query returns the same document more than once but I only want to show it once to the user.